# Pentaho - Issue with Row denormaliser

Tags: pentaho, data-integration, pdi

I'm starting with Pentaho Data-Integration. I'm trying to update my db with data from XML files. However, the `Get data from XML` output is not in the correct format. Then, I use `Row denormaliser` step to do this correction. But, the result is like this:

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1cgF.png

MY transformation is that simple:

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r97uL.png

There's some steps that I can use to Merge this rows? I tried with Merge Rows Diff, Join Rows and Merge Join. None of these steps worked.

Thanks a lot! I'm sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly what you want to acheive, I would suggest you try **"[Group By](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Group+By)"** or **"[Memory Group by](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Memory+Group+by)"** step based on the first column of the data (***TimeStamp***). In the aggregate section of the step, use the type: "sum" based on your remaining columns other than TimeStamp *(Check the image below)*:

[image]

This will aggregate all your rows to one since the timstamp is constant throughout. Use this step after your "row normalizer" step.

Also steps like Merge Rows Diff, Join Rows and Merge Join are used along with two input streams to either join or merge the data into one. It doesn't do any row level aggregation. You can check the pentaho wiki for more :)

Hope it helps :)